# Error : "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal javascript"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(obj).replaceWith('<a class="fd-tool-li" onclick="javascript:Like(this, @Model.User.HOCODE.ToString(), @Model.CommentHOCODE.ToString());">' +
'<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span> ' +UserCount+ ' Like this</span>'+
'<a name="Unlike"class="fd-tool-li" onclick="javascript:Unlike(this, @Model.User.HOCODE.ToString(), @Model.CommentHOCODE.ToString());">(Unlike?)</a>' +
'</a>');
```

Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: I don't see a numeric literal. What are those `@Model.etc.etc.` things?

Comment: Firebug should show you exactly what's causing the error in the error message. My guess is that the `@Model.User.HOCODE.ToString()` is handled server-side, but it's a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code to avoid quote problems (and improve readibility). Extract the onclick javascript from you replace call :

```
$(obj).html('<a class=fd-tool-li onclick="javascript:Like(this, @Model.User.HOCODE.ToString(), @Model.CommentHOCODE.ToString());">' +
    '<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i><span> ' +1+ ' Like this</span>'+
    '<a name=Unlike class=fd-tool-li>(Unlike?)</a>' +
    '</a>'
);

$(obj).click(function() {
   // things
});
```

That's supposing the @Model is defined by a precompiler of some sort and isn't present in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If that's really what your code looks like when it reaches the browser (as opposed to parts of it being handled on the server and something different going to the browser), then you have a syntax error where you have `@Model.CommentHOCODE.ToString()`. You'll need to fix that. Identifiers can't start with a `@`.

If instead that's processed server-side and replaced with a series of characters, you probably need to put quotes around it, if it's really a string.

Similarly, do you have a **client-side** variable called `UserCount`? Because if not, and if that isn't being processed server-side, that could be an issue as well.

Fundamentally you need to look at that code and establish what happens server-side and what the result is that gets sent to the client browser, then ensure that what gets sent to the client browser is valid.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was using an UUID in order to set a complex variable (something + UUID) and an easy solution I did was:

Replace "-" by "", the uniqueness for the identifier keeps alive.

If you are using Razor (ASP.net) instead of doing this: @Model.User.HOCODE.ToString() try with: @(Model.User.HOCODE.ToString())

Regards.